# How to effeciently read and store data from 1GB text file?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a CSV file which contains approximately 1GB of data. The data has 484,000 rows and 60 columns. I have to answer some questions by reading the file, however the data is very large, and I have to efficiently manage the memory. Is there an efficient way to store the data? If I have to store the data in a data structure, which data  structure would be efficient to store/manage the data?

I have to write code in C++. The text file has data which is to be manipulated mostly using the strings. I am using Windows as platform. The file has network errors of a telecommunication company. The data stored contains network faults, and on the basis of those faults, I have to answer some queries.

The data is somewhat like this:

> **"IDENTIFIER","CLEARANCEREPORTFLAG","ESCALATEDALARM","ACKNOWLEDGEMENTUSERIDE","HANDLEDBY","CLOSEDBY","HANDLEDUSERIDENTIFIER","RELEASEUSERIDENTIFIER","CLOSEUSERIDENTIFIER","TERMINATIONUSERIDENTIF","ACKNOWLEDGEMENTTIMESTA","HANDLETIMESTAMP","CLOSETIMESTAMP","TERMINATIONTIMESTAMP","RELEASETIMESTAMP","CREATIONTIMESTAMP","ARCHIVETIMESTAMP","CLEARANCETIMESTAMP","MANAGEDOBJECT","TARGETENTITIES","ALARMTYPE","EVENTTIME","PROBABLECAUSE","SECURITYALARMCAUSE","SPECIFICPROBLEMS","BACKEDUPSTATUS","BACKUPOBJECT","TRENDINDICATION","THRESHOLDINFO","NOTIFICATIONIDENTIFIER","CORRELNOTIFINFO","STATECHANGEDEFINITION","MONITOREDATTRIBUTES","PROPOSEDREPAIRACTIONS","RULENAME","DOMAIN","SECURITYALARMDETECTOR","EXPORTSEQUENCENAME","EXPORTSEQUENCENUMBER","OCNAME","ALARMCLASS","ALARMORIGIN","PARENTALARMOBJECT","ALARMCOMMENT","AGENTALARMIDENTIFIER","AGENTENTITY","PERCEIVEDSEVERITY","ADDITIONALTEXT","ALARMOBJECTOPERATORNO","ORIGINALSEVERITY","ORIGINALEVENTTIME","USERIDENTIFIER","USERTEXT","OUTAGEFLAG","PROBLEMOCCURRENCES","CRITICALPROBLEMOCCURRE","MAJORPROBLEMOCCURRENCE","MINORPROBLEMOCCURRENCE","WARNINGPROBLEMOCCURREN","INDETERMINATEPROBLEMOC","CLEARPROBLEMOCCURRENCE","SATOTAL","EMS_DOMAIN","EMS_VENDOR","EMS_REGION","EMS_LOCATION","FRIENDLY_NAME","NATIVE_CAUSE"
>
> "49487171","1","0","","","","","","Auto-Clear","Auto-Clear","","","8/1/2013
>   5:06:24 AM","8/2/2013 3:28:49 AM","","8/2/2013 3:28:41 AM","8/2/2013
>   5:06:24 AM","8/2/2013 3:51:09 AM","HW_T2000_Sys
>   ihvtfs01_ns:.T2000_Rawalpindi_06 Managed_Element ""33554504"" PTP
>   ""/rack=1/shelf=591070/slot=11/domain=wdm/port=1"" CTP
>   ""/och=1""","1349806175","CommunicationsAlarm","8/2/2013 3:51:09
>   AM","LossOfSignal","","299340460","","","","","","","","","","","Domain
>   ihvtfs01_ns:.National_Tx_Huawei_dm","","EXPORT","1","ihvtfs01_ns:.Nat_Tx_Huawei","0","0","","","","","Major","@Priority=20@FC=FC.TXM.KHI@Outage_Flag=@NE_Name=Karachi
>   MRD:b@USER=:add:
>   T2000_Rawalpindi_06;33554504;/rack=1/shelf=591070/slot=11/domain=wdm/port=1;/och=1
>   native ProbableCause=SM_BIP8_OVER, service
>   affecting=SA_NON_SERVICE_AFFECTING,  nativeEMS
>   Name=T2000_Rawalpindi_06;Karachi MRD;/rack=1/shelf=1246-KHI MRD 2-2 to
>   P/C/slot=11/domain=wdm/port=1;/och=1, additionalInfo =
>   AlarmSerialNo=91292009; AlarmReason=Alarm of OTU layer SM section
>   error threshold crossing; ProductName=OptiX BWS1600G;
>   EquipmentName=ETMXS; AffirmState=FALSE; DetailInfo=Alarm
>   Parameters(hex): 0x01 0x00 0x01 0xff 0xff; , , EMS
>   T2000_Rawalpindi_06 ManagedElement 33554504 PTP
>   /rack=1/shelf=591070/slot=11/domain=wdm/port=1 CTP
>   /och=1@#@1-282@#@BER_SF@#@40 Link
>   INFO:T2000_Rawalpindi_06;Karachi
>   MRD;/rack=1/shelf=591070/slot=11/port=1;/och=1 Link
>   INFO1(wdm):T2000_Rawalpindi_06;Karachi MRD;/rack=1/shelf=1246-KHI MRD
>   2-2 to P/C/slot=11/domain=wdm/port=1;/och=1 NE_Lookup:Karachi
>   MRD__Karachi MRD;/rack=1/shelf=1246-KHI MRD 2-2 to
>   P/C/slot=11/domain=wdm/port=1;/och=1 @AEnd=EMS T2000_Rawalpindi_06
>   Managed_Element Karachi MRD PTP
>   /rack=1/shelf=591070/slot=11/domain=wdm@ZEnd=@SERVICE=::
>   %%%EMS_DOMAIN=Transmission@EMS_VENDOR=Huawei@EMS_REGION=National@EMS_LOCATION=OFS
>   Hall, S/Town@FRIENDLY_NAME=T2000_Rawalpindi_06;Karachi
>   MRD;/rack=1/shelf=1246-KHI MRD 2-2 to
>   P/C/slot=11/domain=wdm/port=1;/och=1;ETMXS@NATIVE_CAUSE=SM_BIP8_OVER+++","","Major","8/2/2013
>   3:51:03
>   AM","","","","1","0","1","0","0","0","1","1","Transmission","Huawei","National","OFS
>   Hall, S/Town","T2000_Rawalpindi_06;Karachi MRD;/rack=1/shelf=1246-KHI
>   MRD 2-2 to P/C/slot=11/domain=wdm/port=1;/och","SM_BIP8_OVER"**

This is the data of first two rows. The first one is like headings of the stored data, the data in the 2nd row is actual data representing faults. Now I have to answer questions like, How many faults have occurred in a specific region etc..

Comment: Depends on what kind of data it contains and on what operations it has to support.

Comment: This ventures into operating system-specific territory. Different operating systems will offer different ways of accessing large files in an optimum way. This is out of scope forC++ itself. You need to specify your operating system.

Comment: What kind of data is in the file? Can't you just process one line at a time without storing everything in RAM?

Comment: If the data doesn't change much, read it into a SQLite database, and work on that.

Comment: The best approach still depends on what kind of questions you want to answer. Because you only have to store the information that you need to answer the questions.

Comment: I have edited the question to describe the nature of the file and type of queries I have to answer.

Comment: I second the sqlite option. Import the data into sqlite and use that in your c++ application.

Comment: I cant use SQL, its an assignment and I am restricted to use data structures like linked list, Trees etc.

Comment: How much RAM do you have available? You could read everything into RAM, storing each line as an object/struct that you then place into an array. That array can then be sorted by different criterea depending on the question you want to answer.

Comment: Actually my system has 16GB RAM, but I have to efficiently manage the memory. It should take least memory.

Comment: A lot of this depends on the data itself. Do you need to store *every* column? Can some values be reduced to constants/bitfields? etc... As such it may be a little broad/under specified atm.

Comment: @Galik yes, actually out of 60 columns I have to store just 20 columns.

Comment: How many of those columns are needed just to perform the search for the information? Just one? or several?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough RAM you could store all strings into one huge array and then you create a struct for each row in which you store pointers to the strings.
Those structs are placed into an array that you can then sort by column.

If you want to minimize RAM usage you could simply read the entire file again for each question. That way you would only have to store the data in RAM that is needed for the current question.

Comment: Wouldn't that decrease the overall performance of the program?

Comment: Yes. The more RAM you are willing to use, the faster you can make the program.

Comment: Can you roughly estimate the total ram usage if I store the whole program in the RAM?. The data is uniform and has 484000 rows.

Comment: @FarazQureshi Depends entirely on how efficiently you store the data.

Comment: Should I use B Trees to store the data, as it would reduce the disk access time?

Comment: And what column would you than use for the keys of that B tree?
The RAM usage should also be around 1GB, maybe a bit more.